# why my code shows segmentation fault.. for n = 1000000000

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#define mod 1000000007

int main()
{

    unsigned long long int n,i,j,k;
    unsigned long long int *power = (unsigned long long int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long int) * (1000000000LL));
    power[0] = 1;
    for(i = 1;i <= 1000000000LL;i++){
        power[i] = (power[i-1] * 2 ) % mod;
    }

    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){

        scanf("%lld",&n);
        unsigned long long int f = 2;
        for(i=2; i<=n;i++){
            f = (f + power[i/2]) % mod;
        }

        printf("%llu\n",f);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `malloc` is unable to allocate the memory for you, it may return a null pointer. Dereferencing one would cause undefined behaviour. You should always check the return value before using is.

Comment: There's no need for the `LL`. An integral literal always has a type in which it fits, if such a type exists.

Comment: @KerrekSB I believe that's a pretty recent behavior though, else why do we have the type suffixes?

Comment: @unwind: Well, you can say `printf("%lu", 1UL)`, but you cannot say `printf("%lu", 1)`...

Comment: [Do not cast the return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @unwind If you call 13 years recent, then yes.

Comment: Does your computer even have 8GB of ram?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a simple explanation of what you're trying to achieve with your code. Also, try reducing your code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - often you will discover the problem during this process. See the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Surely `power[1000000000]` is out of bounds! Your array doesn't have that many elements. You need `<`, not `<=` in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You should check if `malloc` properly allocated `power`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not test the return value of [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc). It fails by giving NULL (e.g. when out of memory).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea

```
for(i = 1;i <= 1000000000LL;i++){
```

indices are zero based anyway but you should replace the `<=` with a `<` to prevent from reading past the end of the array

Also given the size of the array you are trying to allocate you should check your `power` pointer is valid.